# How to update jQuery defaults on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, defaults

This is the section of code I'm trying to adjust:

```
    var documentWidth = jQuery(document).width();
    var documentWidth2 = (documentWidth)/100*2;

    $.Grid.defaults = {
    orientation:      'vertical',
    aspectRatio:      'auto',
    gutterWidth:      documentWidth2,
    gutterHeight:     documentWidth2,
    rows:             3,
    columns:          4,
    onRenderStart:    $.noop,
    onRenderComplete: $.noop,
  };
```

Now, I need 'gutterWidth' and 'gutterHeight' to be variable. I have these values being adjusted on page load, my issue is I need it to also work on window resize. I'm not a complete novice but this is driving me nuts!

I have tried running the function on resize, but whilst the variable is definitely changing (I did a console.log of it), it seems that once that option is set in the code on page load it is no longer able to be updated.

Help!

**FULL CODE HERE:**

```
function myfunction() {
(function (window, $, $window) {

  $.Grid = function (el, options) {
    var that     = this;
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.Grid.defaults, options);

    this.$el     = $(el);
    this.$parent = this.$el.parent();
    this.$items  = this.$el.children();

    // Parse aspectRatio if provided in X:Y format
    if (this.options.aspectRatio != 'auto') {
      var temp = this.options.aspectRatio.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/);
      if (temp && (temp.length == 3) && temp[2]) {
          this.options.aspectRatio = temp[1] / temp[2];
      }
    }

    this.lastRender = {
      width: -1,
      height: -1
    };

    this.render();
    this.$el.transition({ opacity: 1 }, 400);
    $window.on('resize.fluxus-grid-resize', _.debounce($.proxy(that.render, that)));
  };

    var documentWidth = jQuery(document).width();
    var documentWidth2 = (documentWidth)/100*2;

    $.Grid.defaults = {
    orientation:      'vertical',
    aspectRatio:      'auto',
    gutterWidth:      documentWidth2,
    gutterHeight:     documentWidth2,
    rows:             3,
    columns:          4,
    onRenderStart:    $.noop,
    onRenderComplete: $.noop,
  };

  $.Grid.prototype = {


    isHorizontal: function () {
      return this.options.orientation == 'horizontal';
    },

    getItemWidth: function () {
      var totalGutterWidth = (this.options.columns - 1) * this.options.gutterWidth;

      if (this.isHorizontal() && (this.options.aspectRatio != 'auto')) {
        return this.getItemHeight() * this.options.aspectRatio;
      } else {
        return (this.$el.width() - totalGutterWidth) / this.options.columns;
      }
    },

    getItemHeight: function () {
      var totalGutterHeight = (this.options.rows - 1) * this.options.gutterHeight;

      if (!this.isHorizontal() && (this.options.aspectRatio != 'auto')) {
        return this.getItemWidth() / this.options.aspectRatio;
      } else {
        return (this.$el.height() - totalGutterHeight) / this.options.rows;
      }
    },

    calculateCoordinates: function () {
      var that = this,
          coordinates = [],
          maxSize = Math.min(this.options.rows, this.options.columns),
          matrix = new $.GridMatrix({ columnsLimit: this.options[this.isHorizontal() ? 'rows' : 'columns'] });
          itemWidth = this.getItemWidth(),
          itemHeight = this.getItemHeight(),
          rightmostX = 0,
          bottommostY = 0,
          $rightmost = null,
          $bottommost = null,


      this.$items.each(function (index) {

        var $item = $(this),
            itemColumn,
            itemRow,
            size = $item.data('size') || 1,
            width,
            height,
            x,
            y;

        size = size > maxSize ? maxSize : size;

        /**
         * Step 1.
         * Calculate free matrix sport, where current item would fit.
         */
        gridSpot = matrix.getSpot(size);
        matrix.occupySpot(gridSpot[0], gridSpot[1], size);

        /**
         * Step 2.
         * Calculate actual CSS values according to grid position.
         */
        if (that.isHorizontal()) {
          itemRow = gridSpot[1];
          itemColumn = gridSpot[0];
        } else {
          itemRow = gridSpot[0];
          itemColumn = gridSpot[1];
        }

        width = itemWidth * size;
        height = itemHeight * size;

        x = itemColumn * itemWidth;
        y = itemRow * itemHeight;

        /**
         * Step 3.
         * Calculate gutters.
         */
        x += that.options.gutterWidth * itemColumn;
        y += that.options.gutterHeight * itemRow;

        // If size is bigger, then increase items width by the gutter amount it covers.
        if (size > 1) {
          width += that.options.gutterWidth * (size - 1);
          height += that.options.gutterHeight * (size - 1);
        }

        /**
         * Save rightmost and bottommost elements.
         */
        var rightX = x + width;

        if (rightmostX < rightX) {
          rightmostX = rightX;
          $rightmost = $item;
        }

        var bottomY = y + height;

        if (bottommostY < bottomY) {
          bottommostY = bottomY;
          $bottommost = $item;
        }

        coordinates.push({
          width: width,
          height: height,
          x: x,
          y: y,
          rightX: x + width,
          bottomY: y + height
        });
      });

      return {
        'coordinates': coordinates,
        '$rightmost':  $rightmost,
        '$bottommost': $bottommost,
        'rightmostX':  rightmostX,
        'bottommostY': bottommostY
      }
    },


    render: function (renderOptions) {
      this.options.onRenderStart.call(this);

      var windowWidth = $window.width(),
          windowHeight = $window.height(),
          coords;

      renderOptions = renderOptions || {};

      // Check if our context has changed, if not, then there''s no reason to render.
      if (!renderOptions.force && (windowWidth == this.lastRender.width) && (windowHeight == this.lastRender.height)) {
        return false;
      }

      coords = this.calculateCoordinates();

      this.lastRender = {
        width: windowWidth,
        height: windowHeight,
        coords: coords
      }

      this.$items.each(function (i) {
        var $t = $(this),
            c = coords.coordinates[i];

        $t.css({
          width: c.width,
          height: c.height,
          left: c.x,
          top: c.y
        });

      });

      this.options.onRenderComplete.call(this, coords);
    },

  };


  /**
   * Register as jQuery plugin.
   */
  $.fn.grid = function (options) {
    return $(this).data('grid', new $.Grid(this, options));
  };



  /**
   * A data structure for laying out items in a grid.
   */
  $.GridMatrix = function (options) {
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.GridMatrix.defaults, options);

    /**
     * An array of rows, that contains array of column values.
     *
     * Eg.
     *   _matrix = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8] ]
     *   _matrix[0] = 1 2 3 4
     *   _matrix[1] = 5 6 7 8
     */
    this._matrix = [];
  };

  $.GridMatrix.defaults = {
    rowsLimit: 10000,
    columnsLimit: 4
  };

  $.GridMatrix.prototype = {

    set: function (row, column) {
      if (this._matrix[row]) {
        this._matrix[row][column] = 1;
      } else {
        this._matrix[row] = [];
        this._matrix[row][column] = 1;
      }
    },

    _getSpotOnRow: function (rowIndex, size, columnOffset) {
      var size = size || 1,
          row = this._matrix[rowIndex] || [],
          foundAvailableSpotAt = false;

      // Loop 0..columnsLimit positions
      for (var availableAt = columnOffset; availableAt < this.options.columnsLimit; availableAt++) {
        foundAvailableSpotAt = availableAt;

        // Loop CurrentIndex..Size to see if every spot is empty
        for (var i = availableAt; i < (availableAt + size); i++) {
          if (row[i] || (i >= this.options.columnsLimit)) {
            foundAvailableSpotAt = false;
          }
        }

        if (foundAvailableSpotAt !== false) {
          break;
        }
      }

      return foundAvailableSpotAt;
    },

    getSpot: function (size) {
      var currentRow = 0,
          size = size || 1,
          availableSpotFound = false; // Column index.

      while (availableSpotFound === false) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) { // CurrentRow..CurrentRow + size
          var offset = 0;

          /**
           * If we had an available spot in the previous row and now we are checking
           * a proceeding row to see if the same spot is available. We must start from
           * the column, where a free spot was found in the previous row.
           */
          if (availableSpotFound !== false) {
            offset = availableSpotFound;
          }

          availableSpotFound = this._getSpotOnRow(currentRow + i, size, offset);
          if (availableSpotFound === false) {
            break;
          }
        }
        currentRow++;
      }

      return [currentRow - 1, availableSpotFound];
    },

    occupySpot: function (row, column, size) {
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          this.set(row + i, column + j);
        }
      }
    }
  };
})(window, jQuery, jQuery(window));
};
```